# Pine Script / Plotting values only from last highest high

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot values for the variable *test* that come only after a time or bar *moment*. The moment is when `high == highest(high,63)` and from then I would like to plot the *high* values on further bars and not on previous bars. This is possible with *show_last* of the *plot* function, but how can I use an automatic constant for *show_last* which could be the number of bars back when the `first high == highest(high,63)` without using a manual *input*?

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", overlay=true)

moment = valuewhen(high == highest(high,63),time,0)
test = time < moment ? na : high
plot(test, title="test", color=color.yellow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `show_last` for that purpose, because that parameter needs to be an input integer (which value is constant).
You're asking to provide the `show_last` parameter with a `series integer`, but that would lead to a compile error.

I think this is what you want:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", overlay=true)

var bool moment_occurred = false

if high == highest(high,63)
    moment_occurred := true

plot(moment_occurred ? high : na, title="test", color=color.yellow)
```

But once that condition is hit for the first time, it'll always plot af that moment.
It never gets reset.

Comment: Appreciate your help! However, this plots the same values on the whole plot and not just from the moment_occurred which produces the same plot. moment_occurred seems to be true for every bar.

Comment: Yes, that's what I explained in my answer. There'll be a period on the very beginning of the chart where it doesn't plot, but once the condition becomes true, it'll always plot after that moment.

Comment: Understood- seems then there is no other way, but to manually input a number into show_last of the plot